# Mysql - Display ID which occurs more than once

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a column called "job_processing_id", "Description", "Who_marked_it"

My task is to find out any job_processing_id occuring more than once and display it.

I have written the below query :

Select cdh.job_processing_id, cdh.test_counter, tt.test_type, cd.description, u.name, cdh.added_at from call_description_history as cdh left join test_type as tt on tt.id = cdh.test_type_id left join call_description as cd on cd.id = cdh.call_description_id left join user as u on u.id = cdh.added_by where job_processing_id in (SELECT job_processing_id FROM call_description_history group by job_processing_id having count(job_processing_id)>1) and u.id NOT IN (7652, 5225) and added_a

But it also displays ID's that occure only once , which i don't need it.

Can someone help me how to get rid of it please?

Comment: Your query displays counts, not job_processing_ids.

Comment: Can you help me out with it please? i can send you the full query

Comment: I cannot help out with something that I do not understand. Your query in the question only returns counts, not ids. You also have to share sample data, expected output and actual output for us to completely understand your question.

Comment: I have updated the query now. It would be hard to share the sample data as i signed the NDA that might put me in trouble. But to be precise the above mentioned query has to return job_processing_id that occur more than once excluding the one that occurs just once.

Comment: Your query should do the tricks, so does the query in the only answer below. If it does not, then you have to share sample data with us on which your query produces incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT job_processing_id, count(job_processing_id) FROM call_description_history group by job_processing_id having count(job_processing_id)>1;
```

Comment: I have tried that doesn't seem to work. I get ID's which occurs once as well. Here's the full query : Select cdh.job_processing_id, cdh.test_counter, tt.test_type, cd.description, u.name, cdh.added_at from call_description_history as cdh
left join test_type as tt on tt.id = cdh.test_type_id
left join call_description as cd on cd.id = cdh.call_description_id
left join user as u on u.id = cdh.added_by
where  
job_processing_id in (SELECT job_processing_id
FROM call_description_history
group by job_processing_id
having count(job_processing_id)>1) and
u.id NOT IN (7652, 5225) and
added_a